# Ternary statement not working

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

```
1.  document.getElementById('navButton').addEventListener('click', toggleNav);
2.  document.getElementById('menuButton').addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
3.  function toggleNav(){
4.    document.getElementById('nav').className == 'open' ? 'closed' : 'open';
5.    document.getElementById('navButton').className == 'open' ? 'closed' : 'open';
6.  }
7.  function toggleMenu(){
8.    document.getElementById('menu').className == 'open' ? 'closed' : 'open';
9.    document.getElementById('menuButton').className == 'open' ? 'closed' : 'open';
10. }
```

In the above code, I get this error messages next to lines 4, 5, 8, and 9:

> "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression."

I've never had this problem before, and if I just change `document.getElementById('nav').className == 'open' ? 'closed' : 'open';` to `document.getElementById('nav').className = 'open';`, it works just fine. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't assigning the ternary return value to anything. You'll need to do something like this:

`document.getElementById('nav').className = document.getElementById('nav').className == 'open' ? 'closed' : 'open';`

Here's an example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) that is more easily digestible:

```
var elvisLives = Math.PI > 4 ? "Yep" : "Nope";
    ^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^^^^^
//  assignment    condition    expr1    expr2
```

Comment: I feel so dumb. Thank you haha it's been a while since I've coded anything

Comment: No worries! It's actually fairly common to make that mistake :)

Comment: I highly recommend storing `document.getElementById("someId")` inside a variable for easy access, instead of writing that wall of text every single time. Not just for ease of use but because it's easier to read and understand when there's a variable with a name that describes what it is.

Comment: @TiagoMarinho Very true! I used that as an example as adding other stuff would have taken away from the main point that the assignment was missing. Caching the reference is a good idea, especially if there is frequent use.